# Gaussian Processes Clarification

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, gaussian

$\newcommand\mycolv[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}$Hi all, I've been trying to learn all about Gaussian processes for a few days but I find myself stuck on some notation. The book that I have been mainly reading and other articles I've found split up a given multivariate Gaussian distribution into two random vectors $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ where $\textbf{y}$ contains the observed points. This makes sense to me until the redefinition of the gaussian comes up: $$\mycolv{\textbf{x} \\ \textbf{y}} \sim N(\mycolv{\mu_x \\ \mu_y}, \begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_{xx} & \Sigma_{xy} \\ \Sigma_{yx} & \Sigma_{yy}\end{bmatrix})$$

Unfortunately I am not clear on how to compute the values in this definition. Are the mean vectors just the mean of all of the distribution in each random vector i.e some scalar? Or are they a vector simply containing all of the means of each distribution contained in the corresponding vector?

As for the covariance matrix I can imagine having each $\Sigma$ be a covariance matrix, however, since this would cause the dimensions of the $\Sigma_{yx}$ and $\Sigma_{xy}$ matrices to be larger than the other matrices, making multiplication between those two matrices and the other two incompatible. This poses an issue since the product of $\Sigma_{yy}^{-1}$ and $\Sigma_{xy}$ is required when conditioning the multivariate.

Sorry if I made any errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\mu_x$ has the same dimensions as $\mathbf x$ etc.   $\Sigma_{xy}$ has the same number of rows as $\Sigma_{xx}$ has columns  and the same number of columns as $\Sigma_{yy}$ has rows so you can do the multiplications  $\Sigma_{xx}\Sigma_{xy}$ and $\Sigma_{xy}\Sigma_{yy}$ etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. about $\mu_x$ and the dimensions of the matrix blocks. Could you possibly shed some light on how $\Sigma_{xx}, \Sigma_{xy}, \Sigma_{yx}, \Sigma_{yy}$ would be computed? Or maybe shedding light on the dimensions of the matrices with respect to $\textbf{x}$ or $\textbf{y}$ would be enough.

Comment: @user7642735 : \begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_{xx} & \Sigma_{xy} \\ \Sigma_{yx} & \Sigma_{yy}\end{bmatrix} is a covariance matrix. There is no law that tells us how it would be computed. All it needs to be is symmetric and positive semidefinite. The dimensions of the sub matrices have been explained by Henry. Please just read that carefully.